# Show poset in sage enlarging it

Tags: combinatorics, relations, order-theory, sagemath

I happen to have a finite poset, and when there are many elements and relations in my poset and I type Poset.show() (suppose the name of my poset is Poset), it will create the hasse diagram but you can't really see much of it. Is there a way to enlarge the hasse diagram so that this does not happen?

Or if there is a way to expand the cell which gives me the output so that it takes up more space when creating the diagram, this will be very helpful.

I appreaciate any help given.

Answer (score 1):

An inspection of the [relevant page in the Sage documentation](http://doc.sagemath.org/html/en/reference/combinat/sage/combinat/posets/posets.html) shows that in the "Drawing" section, in addition to `show()` there are `plot()` and `graphviz_string()`. The latter would allow you to take it into GraphViz and manipulate it to your heart's content.